# Performance Comparison: Sqlite SELECT f FROM t WHERE rowid = %q VS. Std. C Fopen + Fseek

Tags: c, performance, sqlite

**My Gut Instinct**: *Sqlite3 is going to be the fastest way to read data from a file.*  I'd suspect that they did the engineering, and solved the issues.

**My Fear**: A *C Fopen and Fseek* to a specific rows *would be faster* and use less power.

Got a few databases in sqlite.  Ordered list of strings. Dead simple.  One field and about 300k rows.

```
CREATE TABLE t (f TEXT)
```

I'm doing a binary search against them, using Sqlite, where 'rowid' equals...  Select the middle value.  Check if string is greater than or less than, and divide and conquer.  It's fast as lighting.

```
SELECT f FROM t WHERE rowid = %q
```

The problem is, even when compressing the data fully trained and optimal [entropy encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_encoding), a text file is much smaller.  For example, I have one dataset with the following attributes:

1. Sqlite Text Uncompressed Size: 10.9 MB
2. Sqlite Blob Compressed Fields Size: 8.2 MB
3. Uncompressed Flat Text File: 6.7 MB.

The text file is almost 20% smaller than the compressed Sqlite, and 40% smaller than the uncompressed text.  And, yes, these Sqlite3 databases are Vacuumed.

I could compress and uncompress the strings on the flat text file, and probably get the file size down to 5 MB.

**Question**

So, **anyone know how a *Fopen()/Fseek()* performs compared to a *Sqlite3-Select-Where-'rowid'-equals***?  **Is there any magic that Sqlite3 is doing** in this case, or am I just wasting disk and battery?

I could spend a few hours and figure it out, but I'm sure someone knows, so I figured I'd ask.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this the final size of your dataset, or is this eventually going to be multiple GB of data?  If this is the final size, why not just load the whole thing into memory and search there?  7MB of memory isn't much even on a mobile device

Comment: Not too worried about memory size, and would like to implement a Trie for storing word list in memory.  I'm worried about the load time to read the data from disk.  In Sqlite3, selecting 200-600k rows from disk on a mobile device can take fair amount of time.
Also, probably have to do Fget instead of Fseek.
Fopen opens a stream, and hopping around, even if each row isn't the same length, should be fast enough.
But, yeah, you probably answered the question already.  I'm worried about a non-problem.  Just, apps close to 80 MB total, and don't want to get deleted on devices with limited memory

Comment: perhaps read [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *how a Fopen()/Fseek() performs compared to a Sqlite3-Select-Where-'rowid'-equals?*

It depends on what you actually want to achieve.

1. Your text file contains no rowid's. A SQLite rowid is 8 bytes, so in case of 300k records it would add 2.4MB. If you don't need rowid's, try `CREATE TABLE (...) WITHOUT ROWID`. But it seems you need it since you're querying by it?
2. The text file has no index. So how would you go about finding a row in the middle? Even if you knew the offsets at which each line starts *and* if the lines were sorted, a binary search would incur multiple non-sequential reads from the file (bad for IOPS).
3. If the actual file is just 6.7MB, why not just read it all in and keep in memory? That would be the fastest solution. If not, you need an *index* so that you can know from which *position* to read the file. That is essentially what SQLite provides.

Comment: Definitely need rowid to do binary search in SQLite. Was thinking could just fseek (or whatever appropriate c func is) to middle of file based on size and parse out a word from white space... even if it isn’t exact middle, should work.

Comment: But, gonna try to find a canned implementation of a trie, and see how long it takes to load into memory. Wasn’t considering the rowid as a factor in SQLite file space, but that explains it, so marked it as answered. Thanks

Comment: Another alternative you might want to look into is leveldb. It's a simple key-value store, but is very compact.

Comment: That looks useful. I’m rehabbing a 10-year-old iOS game, that’s actually really nice. I took it of the market for the past or seven years. I think I’m just used to the time that if you allocate 15 mb of memory, you could get your app crashed out by the OS. It’s a word game that is localized. You move tiles around to spell words before the clock stops. But, I want to be able to add blank tiles, and check the dictionary for words that are missing a chara_ter or two, and validate those. Was looking at radix tree and stuff like that. I know there’s been fast scrabble solvers since early 80’s.

Comment: That leveldb does look useful in a lot of places. Over the years, the better I get at programming, the harder it becomes to ship something. I start finding all kinds of issues that no one else would ever notice or care about.